# How to query for multiple values in join table with Spring Data Rest and queryDSL

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, querydsl

I am writing new Spring Data REST back-end for existing and fairly old mySQL database. I need to support free-form search queries and queryDSL seems to be a good candidate. Everything works fine except, that I cannot query for multiple values in join table.

Here are my entities and students repository (in queryDSL I want to default all String match queries to LIKE):

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Students  {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
   private Integer id;

   @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
   private String firstName;

   @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
   private String lastName;

   @Column(name = "major", nullable = false)
   private String major;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "students_courses_joins", joinColumns = {
       @JoinColumn(name = "student_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                   @JoinColumn(name = "course_id") })
   private List<Course> courses;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Courses {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false)
    private String code;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    List<Student> students;
}



RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "students", path = "students")
public interface StudentsRepository extends JpaRepository<Students, Integer>, 
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Students>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QStudents> {

  @Override
  default void customize(@NonNull QuerydslBindings bindings, @NonNull QStudents Students) {
    bindings.bind(String.class).first((StringPath path, String value) -> path.containsIgnoreCase(value));
}
```

DDL to create join table:

```
create table  students_courses_joins
(
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`course_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `student` (`student_id`),
 KEY `course` (`course_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `student` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `students` (`id`) 
 ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `course` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES  `courses`(`id`) ON 
 DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The queries like

```
http://localhost:8081/students?courses.name=XYZ&major=ABC
```

work fine, but as soon as I try to query for students which take multiple courses like

```
http://localhost:8081/students?courses.name=XYZ&courses.name=MN
```

only the first parameter from the join table is accepted and the rest is ignored. So I can only query if a student taking one particular course and cannot query for multiple. Is it limitation of queryDSL or something is wrong with my setup?

According to https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/web-query-dsl-collection-properties.html it should just work, but the second query parameter referring to joined table is always ignored. I also tried to implement custom REST controller instead of relying on one supplied by Spring, but the results are the same/

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the `customize` implementation in your `StudentRepository` like this (use **`all`** that takes `MultiValueBinding` instead of *`first`* that takes `SingleValueBinding`):

```java
@Override                                                                                   
default void customize(@NonNull QuerydslBindings bindings, @NonNull QStudent Students) {    
  bindings.bind(String.class).all((StringPath path, Collection<? extends String> value) -> {
    BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();                                          
    Iterator<? extends String> iterator = value.iterator();                                 
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {                                                            
      builder.or(path.containsIgnoreCase(iterator.next()));                                 
    }                                                                                       
    return Optional.of(builder);                                                            
  });                                                                                       
}
```

With that, you will get a query like this:

```sql
SELECT student0_.id         AS id1_1_,
       student0_.first_name AS first_na2_1_,
       student0_.last_name  AS last_nam3_1_,
       student0_.major      AS major4_1_
FROM   students student0_
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   students_courses_joins courses1_,
                      courses course2_
               WHERE  student0_.id = courses1_.student_id
                      AND courses1_.course_id = course2_.id
                      AND ( Lower(course2_.name) LIKE ? escape '!' ))
        OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   students_courses_joins courses3_,
                          courses course4_
                   WHERE  student0_.id = courses3_.student_id
                          AND courses3_.course_id = course4_.id
                          AND ( Lower(course4_.name) LIKE ? escape '!' ))
LIMIT  ?
```